# How to extract substrings that contain parenthesis with regexp()

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to extract substrings that come before either a left parenthesis or a dot with `regexp()`. For example

```
example1='qwer(1).asdf; qwer(1).zxcv;';

example2='qwer.asdf; qwer.zxcv;';
```

I tried

```matlab
expression='(?<varname>.*?)(\(\d+\)){?}.';

expression='(?<varname>.*?)(?<others>\(\d+\)){?}.';

expression='(?<varname>.*?)\(';

expression='(?<varname>.*?)(';

expression='(?<varname>.*?)/(';
```

with

```
parts=regexp(example1,expression,'names');
```

None worked.

How exactly does matching with parenthesis work in `regexp()`?

The official documentation doesnt mention how to characters that form operators, quantifiers, etc.

Comment: Regex101 is a nice tool to test your regexes. Try something [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqQlIk/1). Not sure, what regex engine Matlab uses but it looks like it supports lookarounds and conditionals, so you can probably use the PCRE test environment on regex101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```matlab
example1 = '01/11/2000  20-02-2020  03/30/2000  16-04-2020';
expression = '(?<varname>\w+)[(.]';
parts=regexp(example1,expression,'names');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWPOeR/1). *Details*:

- `(?<varname>\w+)` - Group "varname": one or more word chars
- `[(.]` - a `(` or `.` char.

Comment: Thanks! Going to leave the question open for a few days in case someone knows of any other ways of matching characters that form quantifiers and operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?<varname>(\S*?)(?:\(.*?;)|(\S*?)(?:\..*?;))/g
```

Here's an illustration of parentheses in regex below. I added the above to actually answer your question

```
 /\(.*?\)/g
```

This will match the parentheses and everything between for each

The \ escapes the parenthesis, the *? matches the smallest amount so it doesn't match everything between the first and last parentheses and the global flag does it for each occurrence

https://regex101.com/ is a great resource

Comment: OP needs to find "*substrings that come before either a left parenthesis or a dot*". Not strings between parentheses.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer with a solution but I think your answer is more concise